# Is the shortest distance between a point and a curve always normal to the curve?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we have some point $P$ and some differentiable function $f$. Then let $P_C$ be a point on $f$ such that $|P-P_C|\le |P-f(t)|$ for any $t$. In other words, $P_C$ is one of the points closest to $P$ and lies on $f$. Intuitively, it seems to me that the line [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) to $f$ at $P_C$ will always intersect $P$. However, I don't know of a proof for this. Is my intuition correct? Is there a proof of this statement? Is this true for all dimensions? If it's not true for all differentiable functions, is there a subset of functions for which it is true?

Comment: 1. continuous function doesn't guarantee that the curve has normal line. 2. Your statement is almost correct, the extreme (minimum, maximum) distances happen either at the normal direction or the singularities (endpoints included).

Comment: @QuangHoang ah, good catch. I forgot about functions like the Weierstrass function. I'll edit my question to ask explicitly about differentiable functions. Is there a well-known proof for your 2nd point?

Comment: Look at the squared distance from $P$ to $f(t)$. This is a differentiable function of $t$ and necessarily minimal at $P_C$, so the gradient at $P_C$ has to be $0$.

Comment: Is your question about curves and points in the 2d plane? Otherwise it can be wrong (unless I am mistaken), e.g. if the image of  $f$ is contained in a hyperplane $H$ and the point $P$  is outside of $H$.

Comment: @MartinR I'm primarily concerned about 2-dimensions, but I am also curious about higher dimensions, simply for curiosity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there seems to be some misconceptions here, let me elaborate a bit on my comment. If $M$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold (a subset that is locally smoothly equivalent to a ball in $\Bbb R^k$) of $\Bbb R^n$, then it has a $k$-dimensional *tangent space* at the point $p\in M$, often denoted $T_pM$. Orthogonal to this $k$-dimensional subspace is the $(n-k)$-dimensional space called the *normal space* of $M$ at $p$, often denoted $N_pM$. Given a point $Q\in\Bbb R^n$, if the point $p\in M$ is *closest* to (or, indeed, farthest from) $Q$, then essentially the calculation that @QuangHoang did will establish that the vector $Q-p$ is orthogonal to $T_pM$, i.e., is an element of the normal space $N_pM$. (You can think of this intuitively as an infinitesimal Pythagorean Theorem.)

The proof, as I suggested, is to parametrize a neighborhood $U$ of $p\in M$ by a ball $B$ in $\Bbb R^k$ by $\varphi\colon B\to U\subset\Bbb R^n$. Let's assume $\varphi(0)=p$.  Now consider the function
$$F\colon B\to\Bbb R, \quad F(s) = \|\varphi(s)-Q\|^2.$$
If $F$ has a (local) extreme point at $0$, then the chain rule tells us that for any vector $v\in\Bbb R^k$,
$$DF(0)v = 2 (\varphi(0)-Q)\cdot D\varphi(0)v = 0,$$
which says that $\varphi(0)-Q = p-Q$ is orthogonal to the image of $D\varphi(0)$. That image is the tangent space $T_pM$.

Answer (score 1):

Corner cases aside, the distance attains minimum/maximum if and only if the square function also attains minimum/maximum

$$g(t) = d^2(t) = \|P-f(t)\|^2$$

On the other hand,

$$\frac{d}{dt}g(t) = 2(f(t)-P)\cdot f'(t)$$

and the statement follows.

Comment: That shows that the gradient of $f$ at that point is perpendicular to $P_C - P$. The question is whether the *normal vector* is parallel to $P_C - P$ (which – unless I am mistaken – can be wrong in 3  dimensions).

Comment: @MartinR Isn't the normal named so because it's perpendicular to the gradient?

Comment: Consider $f(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t), 0)$ and $P = (4, 4, 4)$. At no point does the normal vector of $f$ point into the direction of $P$.

Comment: @MartinR I see. This is a bit different from what I imagine as normal vectors (normal bundle). In which case, you are absolutely correct and OP's statement is not true.

Comment: You make a good point, Martin. Perhaps I'm more interested in functions whose normals (or I believe equivalently, their tangents) fill the entire Euclidean space. I'm not sure if there's a word for such functions, or perhaps a better way to describe them.

Comment: @MartinR You're wrong. The normal space to a curve in $\Bbb R^3$ at each point is a plane, not a line.

Comment: @TedShifrin: That is not my area of expertise, but from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet–Serret_formulas) I concluded that you can define a normal *vector* for a curve in 3D.